# IPTables Configuration Causing Timeout

Tags: ssh, iptables

After adding the drop all rule to IPtables, my SSH terminal takes forever to load, often responding with error `sudo: unable to resolve host foo.bar.domain: Connection timed out`, but then immediately after rendering the error message often responds with the prompt I requested. My pings to the server are consistent. I am running SSH on port 2222.

**IPTables:**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

Comment: add the `-vvv` flags to get the output to be verbose

Comment: I also received this error: `packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Broken pipe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfiguring my IPTables as below solved the issue. (Suggestions taken from [this guide](https://crm.vpscheap.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=29).)

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The two big changes I see are adding the loopback interface, and allowing DNS lookup. (Denying all access by default at the top rather than at the bottom is also cleaner, though I doubt the cause.) Can somebody pinpoint what made the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have enough reputation to comment on [Brandon’s own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004764/802880), so here as an answer:

It is most likely the line

```
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

that fixed it for you. If you are on e.g. a modern Ubuntu version, it uses systemd-resolved which listens on 127.0.0.53:53 - when you perform a DNS lookup, the request is sent to systemd-resolved via the loopback interface (lo).